# Username not inserting and relationships broken

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $users = \App\User::with(['roles','profile'])->get();
    return view('dashboard.users.index',compact('users'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
    $roles = \App\Role::all();
    $countries = \App\Country::all();
    return view('dashboard.users.create',compact('countries','roles'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $user = [
        'username' => $request->username,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    ];
    $user = \App\User::create($user);
           $filename = sprintf('thumbnail_%s.jpg',random_int(1, 1000));
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) 
     $filename = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('profiles',$filename,'public');
 else
    $filename = "profiles/dummy.jpg";
if ($user) {
    $profile = new \App\UserProfile([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'country_id' => $request->country,
        'photo' => $filename,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
    ]);
    $user->profile()->save($profile);
    $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);
    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

}

This is controller

```
@extends('dashboard.layout')
@section('content')
<form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-row align-item-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputUsername"> Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name="username" id="inputUsername" placeholder="UserName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputName">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputName" placeholder="Full Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputUserEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2" name="email" id="inputUserEmail" placeholder="Enter a valid Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputPassword" placeholder="************">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputPhone" placeholder="+923132244567">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="selectCountry">Select Country</label>
            <select name="country" id="" class="form-control">
                @if(!$countries->isEmpty())
                @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control mb-2" id="inputCity" placeholder="Enter Your City Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="selectRoles">Select Roles</label>
            <select name="roles[]" id="selectRoles" class="form-control" multiple>
                @if(!$roles->isEmpty())
                @foreach($roles as $role)
                <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 my-3">
            <label for="inputFileName">Profile Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-custom-control mb-2" id="inputFileName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add New User</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
@endsection
```

This is view

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    // protected $table = 'user';

    protected $primaryKey = 'username';

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * The name of the "created at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';

    /**
     * The name of the "updated at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token','email'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */ 
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    // public static function boot(){
    //     parent::boot();
    //     static::addGlobalScope('vfu',function(Builder $builder){
    //         return $builder->where('email_verified_at',"<>",null);

    //     });

        // public static function boot()
        // {
        //     parent::boot();
        //     static::addGlobalScope(new VerifiedUsers);

        // static::addGlobalScope(new NotVerifiedUsers);

        // static::addGlobalScope('nvfu',function(Builder $builder){
        //     return $builder->where('email_verified_at','=',null);

        //  // App\User::withoutGlobalScope('nvfu')->get();
        // });
    public function scopeVfu($query){
        return $query->where('email_verified_at','<>',null);

    }
    public function scopeNvfu($query){
        return $query->where('email_verified_at','=',null);

    }
    public function scopeFindById($query,$id)
    {
        return $query->where('id',$id);
    }
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class,'user_id','id');
    }
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class,'user_id','id');
    }
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user','user_id','role_id','id');
    }
}
```

This is User Model

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    protected $guard = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class,'country_id','id');
    }
}
```

This is UserProfile Model

```
class Country extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Post::class,UserProfile::class,'country_id','user_id','id','user_id');
    }
}
```

This is Country Model

I have use this code,In this code doens't insert username value i have changed in migration use nullable function and migrate refresh then relationships were broken and when create user and get Add [user_id] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\UserProfile].  error

https://gist.github.com/Hammad964/85fb516517f0bc7163885bff167d29e0 this is github link please any one solve these problems

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you haven't added `username` to your `$fillable` array within your `User` model.

It should be:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'username',
];
```

Update:

In your `UserProfile` model. You have a line that is `protected $guard = [];` but laravel is expecting it to be `protected $guarded = [];`

Doing this allows all columns for the model to be mass assigneable so it is normally advisable to use the `$fillable` approach or to at least add the fields that do not need to be mass assigneable to the `$guarded` array to reduce the security risk for your application.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Hammad are you receiving any errors in your error log? Or are there any exceptiond being thrown? It's worth checking that your migration for the user model does indeed have a `username` column as the default Laravel migration for this model does not.

Comment: @Hammad In your `UserProfile` model, you have a `protected $guard = [];` line. Replace it with `protected $guarded = [];`. That should do the trick.

Comment: I have changed $guard to $guarded and add username in user.php $fillable but did not solved error still getting error

Comment: Username is inserting but user_id cannot be null error still coming

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into user_profiles (user_id, city, country_id, photo, phone, updated_at, created_at) values (?, Karachi, 1, profiles/thumbnail_385.jpg, +923148790984, 2020-02-20 04:49:17, 2020-02-20 04:49:17))

Comment: The `user_id` is required when creating a new `UserProfile`. What you need to do is either, add a hidden input to your form in your blade template that has the `name` of `user_id` and the value of the currently authenticated `user_id`. Or, you can user the Laravel helper method of `auth()->id()` in the controller method and then store the `user_id` for `UserProfile` from that. Basically, as you can see from the error, you are creating the model with all values needed except for `user_id` which is not a nullable column. I hope this makes sense. Show me your controller and I will help you more.